# Routing - Web browser logs out of first instance when second instance is logged in, can I stop this behaviour?

Tags: networking, routes

This is easier to explain with a diagram.

Instance One -> Port 5000 - > Forward to router 5000
Instance Two -> Port 5000 - > Forward to router 5001

Connect to instance One using WANIP:5000, this works fine until I connect to instance two (WANIP:5001).

Web browser logs me out of instance one when I log in to instance two.

How can I stop the web browser from logging me out of Instance one when I connect to instance Two?

I was expecting Instance 1 and Instance 2 to be useable simultaneously.

**What have I tried?**

Check that instance one and instance Two are not on the same IP address. They use the same port currently 5000 - > forward port is differnt for each instance.

I changed the port running on the instance to a differnt one and forwarded that port.

I switched UDP off on the router.

I unticked NAT on the router.

These actions did not resolve my issue.

I can connect to both instances if I use a separate web browser
to connect to each instance. For example, firefox (instance one), Edge (Instance 2).

This does not happen when the instances are on a local lan, behaviour only manifests when the instances are forwarded through the router. If it helps the instance is running .netCore MVC.

Comment: Managed to get a little further, using wireshark it looks like the Cookie in the web browser is getting confused between instances. This cookie contains something called a .AspNetCore.Antiforgery token. Starting to think it might be related to this cookie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question in case anyone else has issues with this.

This seems to be a well known problem involving cookies and the way they are shared via the web browser. Cookies are not (the way we use them anyway) independent for each instance and a new cookie is not generated when the port number changes.

You can use an alias for the IP you are connecting to which then will allow the web browser to have a cookie for each instance.